# К чему относятся такие файлы как подключение к бд, passport, winston и т.д?

Tags: node.js, архитектура

В архитектуре приложения все понятно, views - шаблоны, models - модели и тд. А к чему отнести такие файлы подключение к mongodb, redis, passport, winston и еще много разных модулей?

Comment: В вопросе содержится ответ (как это часто бывает) - такие файлы следует отнести к модулям

Answer (score 0):

Все перечисленное относится к **инфраструктуре**.

Это те вещи, которые не являются частью бизнес логики приложения. Если бизнес логика описывает *что и когда* происходит (она описывает бизнес-правила предметной области), то инфраструктура это детали реализации или механизмы, которые определяют *как*.

Например, интерфейс `CustomerRepository` - часть бизнес-логики приложения, он позволяет коду который непосредственно реализует правила предметной области приложение сохранять и получать модели `Customer`, которые так же являются частью бизнес-логики приложения. Бизнес-логика не знает (не должна по крайней мере) о том, где реально хранится модель, какие механизмы при этом используются и т.д. Этот интерфейс - способ абстагироваться от конкретной реализации.

Реализация же этого интерфейса `MongoDbCustomerRepository` - это уже часть инфраструктуры, которая определяет, как именно хранятся модели.

Вот пример хорошей [статьи](https://khalilstemmler.com/articles/enterprise-typescript-nodejs/clean-nodejs-architecture/) с гораздо более подробным объяснением.

Comment: так здесь вопрос скорее о том, как должна называться папка в которой хранятся файлы подключений к базам, настройки библиотек и тд.

Comment: Это часть инфраструктуры, так и назвать стоит `infrastructure` или `infra`.